# Pandas- TypeError when using pd.read_table parameter, 'converters'

Tags: python, pandas, parameters, temperature, converters

I'm reading in multiple files and want to convert a temperature column using [pd.read_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html) converters. The function I'm using to convert Kelvin to Farenheit works on its own, but doesn't work when using the converters parameter. I get a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'`.

Currently, my DataFrame looks like this

```
             temp
date
2006-01-01  294.6
2006-02-01  294.1...
```

df['temp'].dtype is `dtype('float64')`

My function:

```
def k2f(df):         
     return (df-273.15)*1.8+32.00
#also tried lambda x : (x-273.15)*1.8+32.00
```

Using function on its own:

```
>>>k2f(df)
             temp
date
2006-01-01  70.61
2006-02-01  69.71...
```

How I read in my datafile, df=...:

```
df = pd.read_table('pathto.txt',skiprows=9,delimiter='\s+',
usecols=(0,4),index_col=(0),
names=('date','temp'),na_values=('na'),parse_dates=True,
converters={4:k2f}) #also tried 'temp' keyword to same result
```

Full error message when using df=... above:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mycode.py", line 24, in <module>
    df = pd.read_table('pathto.txt',skiprows=9,delimiter='\s+',usecols=(0,4),index_col=(0),names=('date','temp'),na_values=('na'),parse_dates=True,converters={4:k2f})
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 655, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 411, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 982, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1719, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 890, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:10862)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 912, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:11138)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 989, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:12175)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1112, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:14103)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2274, in pandas._libs.parsers._apply_converter (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:30500)
  File "mmm_a.py", line 20, in k2f
    return (df-273.15)*1.8+32.00
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'
```

As always, any help would be appreciated. This community is great!

Cheers

### Edit/update

***using quotations for the key, '4', seems to rid the error. df=...:

```
df = pd.read_table('pathto.txt',skiprows=9,delimiter='\s+',
usecols=(0,4),index_col=(0),
names=('date','temp'),na_values=('na'),parse_dates=True,
***converters={'4':k2f}) #though 'temp' still doesn't work, same error
```

but, the function isn't being applied to the values. I.E. df prints, but values aren't changed.

Comment: Have you tried to run the function after reading the data? If so, does the same problem occur? If not, have you tried a simpler converter function (like squaring each value)?

Comment: I just tried a squaring function. Yes the function works after reading the data. The data actually isn't read in, "df not defined,"  and the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the documentation properly, maybe the converter should expect a string instead of a float:

> dtype : Type name or dict of column -> type, default None
>
> Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32}
>   Use str or object to preserve and not interpret dtype. If converters
>   are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion.

So maybe what is happening is that the column isn't converted to float, but instead the converter is applied directly to the string being read.

Comment: Ah, that seems to get rid of the error and the dataframe is created. However, the function isn't applied. It might be an issue with the function I made...